# Find the real and imaginary parts of the principal branch of $f(z) = 200^z$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the real and imaginary parts of the principal branch of $f(z) = 200^z$.

My approach was the following, althought I'm a bit stuck (branch cuts are not my strong suit) and any hints would be helpful:

We know that $z = a + ib$ so:

$f(z) = 200^z$

$f(z) = 200^{(a+ib)}$

$f(z) = 200^a \cdot 200^{ib}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from where you left off, with $\ln(z)$ being the principal branch of the natural logarithm:

$$f(z)=200^a\cdot e^{\ln(200)ib}$$

$$f(z)=200^a\cdot(\cos(\ln(200)b)+i\sin(\ln(200)b))$$

$$f(z)=200^a\cos(\ln(200)b)+200^a\sin(\ln(200)b)i$$

So

$$\Re(f(z))=200^a\cos(\ln(200)b)$$

And

$$\Im(f(z))=200^a\sin(\ln(200)b)$$

We don’t need to worry too much about the different branches of this function, it comes from the different branches of the natural logarithm, but as long as we take the principal branch of the logarithm we’re fine.

Answer (score 0):

try $200^z=e^{z\times log(200)}=e^{a\times log(200)}(cos(b\times log(200)+isin(b\times log(200))$

To get principal value $b\times log(200)$ is replaced by $(b\times log(200)) mod(2\pi)$.